# endering text from JSON with Flatlist renderItem - text displays vertically

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a project and encounterede an issue with presenting text from a JSON file. It seems I am handling the JSON correctly, but I can't seem to understand why the text is appearing vertically. Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import jsonquotes from "../../../assets/quotes.json";
import { FlatList, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const text = jsonquotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*jsonquotes.length)].text;
const author = jsonquotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*jsonquotes.length)].from;
const data = text + "-" + author;

class DisplayQuote extends React.Component{
render() {
    return(
        <View>
        <FlatList 
        data={data}
        renderItem={({item})=><Text>{item}</Text>
        }
        />
        </View>
    )
}
}
export default DisplayQuote;
```

And here is a picture that displays the issue. As you can see, the textin the middle box is vertical. How canI change this?

[image: Issue]

Comment: did you try flexDirection?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Text` width is not enough so it renders letters below each other. Try putting `Text` component inside a `View` with `flex:1` style prop or fixed width.